# How can I Travel and Teach English in Thailand?

Tags: budget, work, thailand, legal

I'm struggling to find non-commercial information on teaching English in Thailand in terms of daily costs of living, pay rates for full-time TESOL teachers and the legal requirements (these seem to be changing almost every year!).

Can anyone offer some very up-to-date info on this, preferably in Bangkok, Phuket or Chiang Mai?

Comment: I think you might get a better answer on a forum like Lonely Planet Thorn Tree or a CouchSurfing forum for Thailand or the individual areas.

Comment: Might do, but so far the answers I've found haven't been specific enough, or are quite out of date.

Comment: But did you ask a question of your own or just look at the old ones already there?

Comment: Fair point, was just searching, but Travel.SE is still my first port of call, will be trying some of those next thanks :D

Comment: Hippietrail got it right.  Before you come, surf thaivisa, and ajarn.com.. (that might be spelled wrong.)  Read the stories and info on there, dont be naive and say it wont happen to you.  Farangs dont always fair to well over here.

Comment: A friend of mine recently returned from Cambodia who went as volunteer/teacher. I can pass that person's contact details if needed. PS: 1. I thought of adding this as a comment to above answer, looks I dont have option/privilege! 2. Is it advisable to mention someone's twitter handle here who is not on Stack exchange?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up being tweeted an answer - from a TEFL teacher in Thailand:

[Life and teaching English in Thailand](http://www.teflengland.co.uk/blog/teaching-english-in-thailand-hazeena)

Comment: Very detailed answer!